# How to overwrite the conceal background color with line color?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, conceal

I've started using [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) for NeoVim and I've setup a highlight for a line with error using the following:

```
hi CocErrorLine guibg=#ce2c28
```

However, when the error line has a concealed character, it has a black background.

[image]

How can I use the same background color as the line?

This is the current highlight for the Conceal group:

```
Conceal        xxx ctermfg=109 guifg=#83a598
                   links to phpOperator
```

If it's not possible, is there a way to disable conceal when a line is highlighted?

Comment: Changing the Conceal highlight would change the background of all conceal characters; similarly, disabling conceal would disable it for the entire window

Comment: @D.BenKnoble So there's no way to fix my problem here?

Comment: *I* am not aware of one, but there are many others on the site that may have intelligent insights

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NONE` when you don't want override others syntax groups

`hi Conceal ctermfg=109 guifg=#83a598 ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE`

Comment: It's already set to NONE.